# How can std::less be safer than < when applied to unrelated pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison

I've found out that I should use `std::less` to compare my objects to be able to compare Unrelated pointer (from a different sequences) because just using the relational operator `<` yields UB if used on those unrelated pointers.

- So for practice I've implemented my `compare` function:

  ```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <functional>


    template <class T>
    constexpr int compare(T const& x, T const& y)
    {
        if(std::less<T>()(x, y))
            return -1;
        if(std::less<T>()(y, x))
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }


    int main()
    {
        std::cout << compare(std::string("Hello"), std::string("hello")) << std::endl;
        std::cout << compare(std::string("hello"), std::string("Hello")) << std::endl;
        std::cout << compare(std::string("hello"), std::string("hello")) << std::endl;
        std::cout << compare(-7, 1) << std::endl;

        int* p1{new int(10)};
        int* p2{new int{4}};
        std::cout << compare(p2, p1) << std::endl;

        std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
    }
  ```

The outut:

```
-1
 1  
 0
-1
 1
```

- Why I shouldn't use directly `<` in that case?
- How can be `std::less` safer than `<`? I mean the internals. Thank you!

Comment: You are not comparing character string literals, you are comparing `std::string`s.

Comment: There may be a pointer inside the implementation of `std::string` but that is not what is compared. You're actually comparing the characters in the strings, not their addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can be `std::less` safer than `<`?

Because the standard says so.

> I mean the internals.

On all x64 and most modern architectures `std::less::operator()` is just a simple wrapper over built-in operator `<` or the pointers are casted to `uinptr_t` then compared.

C++ is meant to work on all sorts of hardware architectures so presumably there are architectures out there (historical?, ancient?, weird?) where not all data addresses are (easily) comparable. On those architectures operator `<` wouldn't work while `std::less` is required to implement ways to work.

---

As a side note, you are not comparing pointers in your example

---

> should I use `std::less` instead of `<`

For pointers to (possibly) different objects or within different arrays yes, otherwise if you use `<` in this case you have Undefined Behavior. For anything else no. `std::less` is mostly useful when you need to give a comparator function to some other functions (e.g. `std::sort`).

E.g.:

```
int a{}, b{}
int* p_a = &a;
int* p_aa = &a;
int* p_b = &b;

p_a < p_b; // technically Undefined Behavior, use std::less instead:
std::less<>{}(p_a, p_b);

p_a < p_a; // ok
p_a < p_aa; // ok
```

```
int arr1[10]{}
int* p1_1 = &arr1[0];
int* p1_2 = &arr1[5];

int arr2[10]{};
int* p2_1 = &arr2[0];
int* p2_2 = &arr2[5];

p1_1 < p2_1; // technically Undefined Behavior, use std::less instead:
std::less<>{}(p_1_1, p_2_1);

p1_1 < p1_2; // ok
p2_1 < p2_2; // ok
```

```
char str[] = "hello";
char* str_end = str + strlen(str);

for (char* p = str; p < str_end; ++p) // ok
    // ...
```

For anything else use `<`

```
int a{}, b{};
a < b; // ok

std::string s1{}, s2{};
s1 < s2; // ok
```

Comment: @Maestro `x` and `y` are references to `const std::strings` so you are comparing `std::strings`. You need to either pass addresses or compare `&x` and `&y`

Comment: Ok get it now. I am so sorry for disturbing you with these such stupid questions. But one thing: should I use `std::less` instead of `<`?

Comment: @Maestro for pointers to different objects yes, otherwise you have Undefined Behavior. For anything else no, `std::less` is mostly useful when you need to give a comparator function to some other functions (e.g. `std::sort`)

Comment: I didn't understand "for pointers to different objects yes, otherwise you have Undefined Behavior" you mean I'd have UB when using `<` not `std::less` right?

Comment: @Maestro you are welcome. Anyway you should extremely rarely find yourself in need to compare pointers in C++.

Comment: "On all x64 and most modern architectures std::less::operator() is just a simple wrapper over built-in operator <." You can easily check that this is wrong for libstdc++, look at the file bits/stl_function.h.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, it does a built-in `<` if the values are constant evaluated, otherwise it casts the pointers to `uintptr_t`. In libc++ as far as I can see there is no specialization for pointers so it does just `<` over the pointers.